# How to Group By in MongoDB with this case

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Let say we have `posts` table like this

```
id   |   friend_id   |  title  |
- -  |  - - - - - -  | - - - - |
 1   |      2        | John    |
 2   |      5        | John    |
 3   |      4        | John    |
 4   |      4        | Joe     |
 5   |      5        | Amy     |
 6   |      2        | Amy     |
 7   |      2        | Joe     |
```

I want a query that will group the rows by `title` and return a one row with an array of friend_id.

Result could be sth like that:

```
{
  John: { id: 1, title: John, friend_id: [2,5,4] }
  Joe: { id: 4, title: Joe, friend_id: [4,2] }
  Amy: { id: 5, title: Amy, friend_id: [5,2] }
}
```

I know the above example is not a real one! Just to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This query

```
db.posts.group(
   key: {title: true}
   , initial: {friend_ids : []}
   , reduce: function(doc, out){ out.push(doc.friend_id) }
   } );
```

would return results like

```
{
 [{title : "John", friend_ids : [2,5,4]} , ....]
}
```

Comment: Here is what i tried to get it work with Ruby `Post.collection.group({ key: ["title"], initial: {friend_ids: []}, reduce: "function(doc, out){ out.push(doc.friend_id) }"})` But it returns error: `Mongo::OperationFailure: Database command 'group' failed: (errmsg: 'exception: reduce invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: out.push is not a function reduce setup:1'; code: '9010'; ok: '0.0').`

Comment: The reduce function should look like this:  `function(doc, out){ out.friend_ids.push(doc.friend_id) }`
The 'friend_ids' was missing in the original answer.

Note that it will work fine for a small amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this `pivoting` with mongodb using map reduce. There is a nice example in [The MongoDB Cookbook](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/pivot/). please take a look. Its not that hard, you can do it yourself.